# Add an extra field to Odoo 11.0 Account Invoice

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-10, odoo-11

I want to add an extra field to sales invoice which in inherited from `account.invoice` . More specifically i want to add a field `delivery_date` to each invoice line item.

```
from odoo import api, fields, models, _
from odoo.exceptions import ValidationError
from datetime import date


class ReadyMixSalesInvoice(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'account.invoice'
    _name = 'account.invoice'

    delivery_date = fields.Datetime(string='Delivery Date', required=True, readonly=True, index=True,
                                    states={'draft': [('readonly', False)], 'sent': [('readonly', False)]},
                                    help='Item delivery date.')

    @api.constrains('delivery_date')
    def _delivery_date_check(self):
        for record in self:
            if record.delivery_date and record.delivery_date.split(' ', 1)[0] < str(date.today()):
                raise ValidationError(_("Delivery Date must be after current date."))
```

and XML is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo>
    <record id="invoice_form_inherit_sale_ready_mix" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">account.invoice.form.readymix</field>
        <field name="model">account.invoice</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="account.invoice_form"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <data>
                <xpath expr="//field[@name='price_unit']" position="after">
                    <field name="delivery_date"/>
                </xpath>
                <xpath expr="//tree/field[@name='price_unit']" position="after">
                    <field name="delivery_date"/>
                </xpath>
            </data>
        </field>
    </record>

</odoo>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to add new field to invoice lines you need to inherit `account.invoice.line`.
Here you inherited `account.invoice`, Inherit `account.invoice.line` and try again.

Eg:

```
class ReadyMixSalesInvoice(models.Model):
_inherit = 'account.invoice.line'
_name = 'account.invoice.line'

delivery_date = fields.Datetime(string='Delivery Date', required=True, readonly=True, index=True,
                                states={'draft': [('readonly', False)], 'sent': [('readonly', False)]},
                                help='Item delivery date.')

@api.constrains('delivery_date')
def _delivery_date_check(self):
    for record in self:
        if record.delivery_date and record.delivery_date.split(' ', 1)[0] < str(date.today()):
            raise ValidationError(_("Delivery Date must be after current date."))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add it to invoice line the model is `account.invoice.line`.
In you case you do not need to specify the `_name` attribute because it is
already inherited from the parent model..

In your python code:

```
class ReadyMixSalesInvoice(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'account.invoice.line'
```